# Usb tethering does not work but pdanet does

Tags: tethering

Here's my problem: If I go to the built-in android tethering system and enable it, the computer connects just fine but it does not have internet access(the yellow icon is there). However, I installed [pdanet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet&hl=en) and it works great but the free version is limited :/.

How can I get the built-in tethering to work?

Info:

I installed the adt and I can upload programs to the phone via usb with no problem.
Brand: LGE720
Android: Android 2.2 Kernel 2.6.32(there is no newer version for this phone)
I only want usb tethering.

Let me know if you need additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Android offers a standard usb-network adapter (implemented in software) to accomplish usb tethering.

The problem can be on the PC side or on the Android phone's side as well.

Some hints for debugging:

- Do you see that usb network device on your PC if you enable tethering?
- If so, do you get a DHCP offer from that "USB network card" on your PC?
- Can you ping the phone gateway from your PC (usually `ping 192.168.4.129`)?
- Can you resolve DNS entries (`nslookup google.com`)?
- Can you ping a random host on the internet (eg. `ping google.com`)?

To view debug logs on the phone use a [logcat viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) and see for obvious entries.

If the problem is your phone software and you're willing to void your warranty, the aftermarket CyanogenMod firmware also offers this functionality, as well as several other custom ROMs (your phone seems to be supported, according to [CM's device overview](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/E720_Info)).

Comment: Thanks for answering. The phone does make a dhcp server and I can ping the phone gateway. However, I cannot resolve the DNS entries nor ping a host on the internet. I also installed cyanogenmod, but that made it worse(no DHCP server/usb network device). Oh and thanks for pointing out the link to cyanogen, it looks and works a lot better than the stock rom :).